# JS window.location.href and cross origin policy

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

As I know, when iFrame from domain a.com tries to get or set `top.location.href` on domain b.com, it breaks same origin policy and "Access Denied" error thrown.

What can cause to such behavior not to work?? I was very surprised when in our test application, iframe from site  www.test-a.com success to set `top.location.href` on www.test-b.com to other-site.com?

The question is specially about using `top.location.href = 'other-site.com'` and not `top.location = 'other-site.com'`?